# Anyone with a Ricoh YF-20 please?

Tags: film, point-and-shoot, vintage

My cousin gave me a Ricoh YF-20 for my birthday and if anyone owns the same camera, can you help me to figure out this baby?

Comment: If you have a specific question you can ask it here, but this isn't intended as a match making service and we can't really answer the overly broad question of explaining the entire camera outside of linking you a manual.  We can provide much more assistance if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the [YF-20 Owner's Manual](http://www.cameramanuals.org/ricoh_pdf/ricoh_yf-20.pdf).